# rotate="false" not working in ui-bootstrap/angular-data-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using  **`ui-bootstrap`** `v0.14.3` and http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/bootstrap/

According to `angular-data-grid` docs

> **`rotate`** (Defaults: `true`) : Whether to keep current page in the middle of the visible ones.

So I added `rotate = "false"` in my code

```
<div grid-pagination boundary-links="true"
                             rotate="false"
                             ng-if="paginationOptions.totalItems  > paginationOptions.itemsPerPage"
                             total-items="paginationOptions.totalItems"
                             ng-model="paginationOptions.currentPage"
                             ng-change="reloadGrid()"
                             class="pagination-sm"
                             items-per-page="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage">
                        </div>
```

Not working for me.

Comment: can you provide a minimal, verifiable example that reproduces the issue? in snippet here or a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `max-size="5"` in my code now it's working fine

```
<div grid-pagination max-size="5"
     boundary-links="true"
     rotate="false"
     ng-if="paginationOptions.totalItems  > paginationOptions.itemsPerPage"
     total-items="paginationOptions.totalItems"
     ng-model="paginationOptions.currentPage"
     ng-change="reloadGrid()"
     class="pagination-sm"
     items-per-page="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage">
</div>
```